# LoopJ Android Asynchronous Http Client onpostexecute?

Tags: android, apache, loopj

I am making a GET call and am able to add all the results into an array after parsing the JSON. I want to use that array onpostexecute call. Can I do that with this library?

Answer (score 0):

I do it in this way , hope it will  help you.

in bussiness layer

```
HttpUtils.getJson(url, null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
 @Override
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject      response) {
}
});
```

in HttpUtils.java

```
private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
public static void get(String urlString, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler res)   //url里面带参数
{
    client.get(urlString, params, res);
}
```